# Instead of the specified Texture, black circles on a green background are getting rendered. Why?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm trying to render a Texture via OpenGL. But instead of the texture black circles on a green background are rendered. (They scale, depending what the rotation of the texture is)

**Example:**

[image]

**The texture I'm trying to render is the following:**

[image]

**This is the code I use to render the texture, it's located in my Sprite-class.**

```
    public void Render()
    {
        Matrix4 matrix = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(-OriginX, -OriginY, 0) *
                        Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) *
                        Matrix4.CreateTranslation(X, Y, 0);


        Vector2[] corners =
        {
            new Vector2(0,0), //top left
            new Vector2(Width ,0),//top right
            new Vector2(Width,Height),//bottom rigth
            new Vector2(0,Height)//bottom left
        };

        //copy the corners to the uv coordinates
        Vector2[] uv = corners.ToArray<Vector2>();

//transform the coordinates
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) corners[i] = new Vector2(Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(corners[i]), matrix));
        //GL.Color3(TintColor);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, _ID);
        GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                GL.TexCoord2(uv[i]);
                GL.Vertex3(corners[i].X, corners[i].Y, _layerDepth);
            }
        }
        GL.End();

        if (EnableDebugDraw)
        {
            GL.Color3(Color.Violet);
            GL.PointSize(3);
            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Points);
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) GL.Vertex2(corners[i]);
            }
            GL.End();

            GL.Color3(Color.Green);
            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Points);
            GL.Vertex2(X, Y);
            GL.End();
        }

    }
```

**This is how I setup OpenGL.**

```
    public static void SetupGL()
    {
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.AlphaTest);
        GL.AlphaFunc(AlphaFunction.Greater, 0.1f);

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
        GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);

    }
```

**With this function I load the texture:**

```
public static uint LoadTexture(string path)
    {
        uint id;
        GL.GenTextures(1, out id);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, id);

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(path);

        BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, data.Width, data.Height, 0,
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);

        bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
        return id;
    }
```

**And here I call Sprite.Render()**

```
protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        GL.ClearColor(Color.MidnightBlue);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
        _sprite.Render();
        SwapBuffers();
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);
    }
```

As I stole this code from the Textures-Example from OpenTK, I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your UVs look suspicious to me:

```
    Vector2[] corners =
    {
        new Vector2(0,0), //top left
        new Vector2(Width ,0),//top right
        new Vector2(Width,Height),//bottom rigth
        new Vector2(0,Height)//bottom left
    };

    //copy the corners to the uv coordinates
    Vector2[] uv = corners.ToArray<Vector2>();
```

Normally the UVs for a sprite would range from 0 to 1, not from 0 to width/height.  This is probably why you've got a bunch of circles showing up; your UV mapping is accidentally squeezing the texture down to a tiny size and causing those circles to appear as an artifact.

Second, your texture loading logic looks suspicious.  Your `LockBits` call specifies ARGB format, while your `TexImage2D` call specifies RGBA internal format.  I'm not sure which is the correct one, but presumably they should match.  This could be why the texture is turning green and black - the color channels are getting swapped around wrongly.

Comment: You're right. That's the reason there are multiple circles. The uv space is [0,1] and by default the sampler wraps around when the index is out of bounds.

Comment: With the fixed uvs I now see my picture, however the colors are strange (white is green). According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645368/opengl-c-sharp-opentk-load-and-draw-image-functions-not-working the format is correct

Comment: When I disable the debug-view, my texture gets rendered correctly :)

Comment: @vinzBad Ahh, that's because the `GL.Color3(Color.Green)` in the debug-draw code is remaining in effect.  You can cancel it by adding a call to set the color to white before drawing your sprites.

Comment: yep, this solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a close look at this part of the code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(path);

BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(
    new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, 
    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb
);

GL.TexImage2D(
    TextureTarget.Texture2D, 
    0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, 
    data.Width, data.Height, 0,
    OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, 
    PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0
);
```

There seems to be a difference between the format of your BitmapData ( Format32bppArgb ) and the format you specify to `GL.TexImage2D`.

Also, having a quick look at the API page for [glTexImage2D](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glTexImage2D.html) you can see that the *internalformat* and *format* parameters must have the same value. Yours differ: Rgba, Bgra. Make sure you use the same format everywhere ( namely Argb ).

Hope this helps.

Comment: According to this is the format just right: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11672859/725126