# I enabled and setup glBlendFunc, but my texture has a white outline. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

You can see most of my source code in this question: [Instead of the specified Texture, black circles on a green background are getting rendered. Why?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/44085/21937)

Now I have the problem, that my texture has a white outline on its transparent parts. After googling and setting up glBlendFunc, the outline just got "softer".

This is how it looks like:

[image: Teh bug]

This is how I now setup OpenGL:

```
    public static void SetupGL()
    {
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
        GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
        GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);

    }
```

Comment: Perhaps setting textures to be nearest instead of linear. Also, make sure your texture does not actually have a outline.

Comment: setting the Filters to Nearest solved it, thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use pre-multiplied alpha for transparent textures that you intend to do alpha blending on. That will solve the color bleeding you're seeing.

First, make sure to multiply the RGB values of your texture with the A.

Second, use glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) as the blend mode.

Comment: how do I accomplish this? should I loop through all pixels of my image and multiply them? I use a .png, I thought it already has premultiplied alpha?

Comment: PNG stores unassociated (non-premultiplied) alpha. You'll have to premultiply the pixels yourself after loading, before calling glTexImage2d. Loop through the pixels and multiply (color.rgb *= color.a).

Answer (score 1):

You should try setting your textures to `GL_NEAREST`. It looks like you're using `GL_LINEAR` which could make your textures not be "crisp" on the edges where you want them to be.

Comment: This isn't a long-term solution and will look ugly once the sprite starts moving, especially when it gets bigger. Premultiplying alpha or choosing an appropriate background color will work much better in this case.

Comment: @snake5 Good plan.

Comment: Just do little OpenGL I thought, 2D would be easy I thought :( now stuff gets strange...